# Composite FK with nullable fields

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, rdbms

I have 3 tables:

- `NETWORK_OPERATOR`s;
- `NETWORK_CELL`s: each of them belongs to one `NETWORK_OPERATOR`;
- `IRI`s: each of them can have **either**:

  1. a *Network Operator* **or**
  2. a *Network Cell*

but one of 1) and 2) is mandatory.

In case of 1) the `netOpId` must exists in `NETWORK_OPERATOR` table;

In case of 2) the `cellId`+`netOpId` must exist in `CELL` table;

Here is a sample DDL code:

```
CREATE TABLE "NETWORK_OPERATOR" (
  "NETOPID" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT "NETWORK_OPERATOR_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("NETOPID")
)

CREATE TABLE "NETWORK_CELL" (
  "CELLID" INTEGER  NOT NULL, 
  "NETOPID" INTEGER  NOT NULL, 
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(20), 
  CONSTRAINT "NETWORK_CELL_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CELLID"),
  CONSTRAINT "CELL_NETOPS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("NETOPID") REFERENCES "NETWORK_OPERATOR" ("NETOPID")
)

CREATE TABLE "IRI" (
  "IRIID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "NETOPID" INTEGER,
  "CELLID" INTEGER,
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT "IRI_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("IRIID"),
  CONSTRAINT "IRI_NETOPS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("NETOPID") REFERENCES "NETWORK_OPERATOR" ("NETOPID")
)
```

**In other words**,

a `NETWORK_CELL` is itself always bound to a `NETWORK_OPERATOR`, so that **IF** a `IRI` has a `netOpId` it should be enforced to be an existing `netOpId`, **ELSE IF** a `IRI` has a `cellId`+`netOpId` it should be enforced to be an existing `cellId`+`netOpId`

I see 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Make only `IRI.NETOPID NOT NULL`able and add a composite FK

```
    CREATE TABLE "IRI" (
      ...
      "NETOPID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
      "CELLID" INTEGER,
      ...
      CONSTRAINT "IRI_CELL_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("CELLID", "NETOPID") REFERENCES "NETWORK_CELL" ("CELLID", "NETOPID")
```

)

(of course there will be a Unique key on `"NETWORK_CELL" ("CELLID", "NETOPID")`)

In other words, an IRI will have a mandatory FK relationship with a Network Operator, and an optional FK relationship with a Network Cell.

The "suspect" thing is that this "optional" FK is composed by a mandatory field and an optional one, on IRI side.

*Oracle RDBMS accepts this (I just tried), but is it a good practice?*

**Option 2:**

Same FK, like in option 1, but leave `IRI.NETOPID` nullable and add a custom constraint that enforce **either** `netOpId` **or** `netOpId`+`cellId`

*I feel this solution more portable, but maybe I'm wrong.*

**The question**

Are there better options?

What's the best practice to deal with this situation and why?
I'm thinking about portability to other RDBMS, too...

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance in Database Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279765/inheritance-in-database-design)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Google sql/database subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism. Also many/multiple FKs to many/multiple tables (anti-pattern). You should find these googing--Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. PS Almost always the simplest & most straightforward design is found starting without NULLs. You can always use NULL by left joining to new base tables.

Comment: @philipxy My question has nothing to do with inheritance. I carefully _googled_ for a best practice about this kind of relationship but couldn't find an answer. By the way, thank you for your suggestion. I'll try to be more clear in my explanation.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Your if-elseif doesn't make sense since if a IRI doesn't have a netOpId then it doesn't have a cellId+netOpId so the elseif is never satisfied. The "have" & "+" seem to be hiding some language. Eg in a comment you say "if it *just* has an op ...". Similarly "always bound to" is not clear, it's just something vague that you immediately try to give a consequence of. (Which I guess is supposed to be a definition? But you start "so" not "ie".) PS The way FK default MATCH SIMPLE works, a FK with a NULL is satisfied. So you can have FKs (netid), (cellid) & (netid, cellid).

Comment: Subtyping is an issue here. There are two *types* of thing of the *type* of thing that an IRI can "have". [Here's another link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3579079/3404097). I'd agree that that might not be the only design issue here.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my native language. I agree about your _if..else if_ point from a strictly sintactical point of view. Moreover, I was mixing pseudo-code and code. But I'm happy you could understand my question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option 1 is OK. The way default  FK (foreign key) declaration mode MATCH SIMPLE (usually the only one implemented) works, a FK subrow value with any NULLs satisfies its constraint. So you can have IRI FKs (netid) & (netid, cellid)--plus netid NOT NULL. (You seem to have forgotten the NOT NULL in your first IRI though not the second.)

Then the only cases for the column pair are (non-null, null) & (non-null, non-null). A netid must exist; a non-null cellid must exist with that netid & a NULL cellid is OK.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding one solution could be this one:

```
CREATE TABLE IRI (
  IRIID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NETOPID INTEGER,
  CELLID INTEGER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT IRI_PK PRIMARY KEY (IRIID),
  CONSTRAINT IRI_NETOPS_FK FOREIGN KEY (NETOPID) REFERENCES NETWORK_OPERATOR (NETOPID),
  CONSTRAINT IRI_CELLS_FK FOREIGN KEY (CELLID) REFERENCES NETWORK_CELL (CELLID),
  CONSTRAINT IRI_CELL_OR_NETOP CHECK ( NVL(NETOPID, CELLID) IS NOT NULL )
)
```

If you like to enforce that only of value is set you can use

```
CHECK ( NVL(NETOPID, CELLID) IS NOT NULL AND NOT (NETOPID IS NOT NULL AND CELLID IS NOT NULL) )
```

or

```
CHECK ( NVL(NETOPID, CELLID) IS NOT NULL AND NETOPID||CELLID IN (NETOPID, CELLID) )
```

or

```
CHECK ( (NETOPID IS NULL AND CELLID IS NOT NULL) OR (NETOPID IS NOT NULL AND CELLID IS NULL) )
```

Comment: Thank you, but the key of this topic is that a `NetworkCell` is itself bound to an Operator, so that if a `IRI` has just an Operator it should be bound to `NETWORK_OPERATOR` on `NETOPID` only, but if a `IRI` has a Cell it shoud be bound to  `NETWORK_CELL` on `NETOPID + CELLID`. I'll try to make it more clear in the question.